# Add to Homescreen from within application?

Tags: iphone, ios, web-applications, iphone-standalone-web-app

Apps like Icon Project show that you can let your app make a homescreen icon with a link to a website. Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?? I dont know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icon project submits data to a php based website which then shoots out an html to your browser ... 
This html is nothing but a web app which is cached and stored to your homepage ... 
information on setting the web app icon and caching can be found on 
http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/html5-iphone-app/

Comment: I just downloaded the App and it was indeed that stupid ;-) Thank you for the time to answer. So basically, what I want to do is that if someone clicks on a link in my application it will be asked if it want a home screen icon of that link, that wouldn't be possible from within the app?

Comment: No, you cannot do that directly from the app ... u will have to redirect the user to safari and from there the user will have to add the icon to home screen ...